# Riak secondary index search returns no keys every time

Tags: php, riak, riak-search

I must be crazy... I've got the search function working for my bucket just fine. Keys are returned nicely.

But when my php riak object contains:

```
    ["indexes":protected]=>
        array(2) {
            ["sign_id_int"]=>
            array(1) {
               [0]=>string(4) "1655"
            }
    ["eth0_bin"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>string(17) "00:11:22:33:44:57"
        }
    }
```

and I do 
    $results = $bucket->indexSearch("eth0", "bin", "00:11:22:33:44:57");

I get a null array.

When I go to my URL directly:

localhost:8098/buckets//index/eth0_bin/00:11:22:33:44:57

it returns a JSON object "keys" with nothing in it.

HOWEVER, when I query the sign_id / int index, I do get a result.

What am I doing wrong? Driving me mental...

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... The first problem was using setIndex, and not using addIndex -- index wasn't getting stored properly. Secondly, ":" is a special char it would seem. Guess that makes sense as the interface relies on http.